# Advanced custom field on product shows in edit order page but not on order preview

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF to store some information on each product that i then want reflected in the admin area. I have got it working on the edit order page for both simple and variable products with the following:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'downloadable_items', 100, 3 );
    function downloadable_items( $item_id, $item, $product ){
    // Only on backend order edit pages
    if( ! ( is_admin() && $item->is_type('line_item') ) ) return;

    // Get your ACF product value (replace the slug by yours below)
    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
    if ( $acf_value = get_field( 'downloadable_image', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $acf_label = __('Download Link: ');

        // Outputing the value of the "downloadable item" for this product item
        echo '<div class="wc-order-item-custom">'  . $acf_label .'<a href="'. $acf_value 
    .'">'. $acf_value . '</a></div>';
    }} else {
    if ( $acf_value = get_field( 'downloadable_image', $product->get_parent_id() ) ) {
        $acf_label = __('Download Link: ');

        // Outputing the value of the "downloadable item" for this product item
        echo '<div class="wc-order-item-custom">'  . $acf_label .'<a href="'. $acf_value 
    .'">'. $acf_value . '</a></div>';
    }}
    }
```

I would like this to also reflect in the order preview so as not to have to load into each order. Hopefully that makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You have to create column and populate it with your data https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/columns.html

Comment: Thank you Martin, I'm trying to add it to the order preview screen though as a column wouldn't work well for orders with multiple items in. The order preview is also loaded by ajax which allows for the page speed not to be affected on initial load